# How to show the "Install Twitter" in the Chrome address bar?

Tags: google-chrome, installation

How do I add a button similar to "Install Twitter" in the Google Chrome address bar? Any document where this functionality is described?

[image: Install Twitter download button in chrome address bar]

I create an application that interacts with a web page and needs to provide a user with the download link for my application to be installed on the client machine.

Comment: Is this actually a question about the Twitter API / programming interface or is this basically asking how to make an installable web app? If this is not related to a Twitter can you delete the Twitter tag from the post?

Comment: This question about how to make an installable web app from chrome web store.

Comment: So, it’s not about Twitter. Removing that tag then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called [Progressive Web Apps (PWAs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_application). Requirements for the installation button in the address bar could be found [here](https://web.dev/install-criteria/).

iOS provides similar technology called [Apple App Clip](https://developer.apple.com/app-clips/).